# Unable to decode data from db (Php LAravel 5.3)

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3

I am working on laravel app and I am saving my data in JSON encoded form as

```
{"name":"Ali","email":"testdc@gamil.com"}
```

It shows as above in db text field

In my method I am getting data as

```
function users($id, Request $request)
{
    $method = $request->method();

    if($request->isMethod('GET')) {

        $users = DB::table('user_settings')->select('notification_setting')->first();
        print_r( $notification_smtp);
        die;

        return view('setting/user');
    }
}
```

Below is the output of the code above:

```
stdClass Object ( [notification_setting] => {"name":"Ali","email":"testdc@gamil.com"} )
```

**If I try to decode it it gives an error as json_decode 2nd parameter should be string object passed**

How can I get the response to this format?

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => Ali [email] => test@gmail.com )
```

How can I possibly achieve that?

Comment: Can you post the statement used to decode JSON?

Comment: it says as json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Yes, what we need is the method / statement you used in your code to decode JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, `print_r( json_decode($notification_smtp->notification_setting) );`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try serialization? like get a tmp variable with parsed object

```
//your code
$users = DB::table('user_settings')->select('notification_setting')->first();
                print_r( $notification_smtp);
                die;
//try this
$tmp = (string) $user;
dd($tmp);
```

if not help, read laravel doc, its really good.

[Laravel Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization)

If still no helping you, google serialization and unserialization  ;)